# logging dynamic data in c++

Tags: c++, logging, sequence

I have a few dynamic queue in my program which can add element at back or middle/remove from front during the processing and never stores the elements in memory once processing is done.However I want to log/serialize the dynamic state of the sequences including all removed elements for the introspection purpose.

e.g.

```
    struct element1{};
    struct element2{};
    std::deque<element1> v1;
    std::deque<element2> v2;

    if(some_cond1)
    {
       v1.push_back(element1{});
       //log v1.back()
       v1.push_back(element1{});
       //log v1.back()
    }
    if(some_cond2)
    {
       v2.push_back(element2{});
       //log v2.back()
       v2.push_back(element2{});
       //log v2.back()
    }
    if(another_cond)
    {
       v1.pop_front();//presently I am not logging removal of elements
       v2.pop_front();
    }
    if(a_third_cond)
    {
       v1.insert(some_pos,element1{});
       //log v1,some_pos
    }
```

I am looking at two alternative solution.

- Is there some data format (say JSON) which allows array/object to be distributed over different location and referenced through some unique name/id as I do not preserve all the elements ready in memory to write to a file and log only part of the sequence as I go?

e.g.

```
   { 
     "v1" : [],
     "v2" : [],
     append("v1"):
     [
        "elem1_v1", "elem2_v1"
     ],
     append("v2"):
     [
        "elem1_v2", "elem2_v2"
     ],
     insert("v1",1):
     [
        "elem3_v1"
     ]
   }
```

- Is it possible to write to multiple different locations to a single file so that each sequence tracks its own location and writes to that location so that end result is simple contiguous sequence description? (All i can think of something like a file backed SGI rope implementation)

In this case, the end result may look like,

```
   { 
     "v1" : ["elem1_v1","elem3_v1","elem2_v1"],
     "v2" : ["elem1_v2","elem2_v2"]
   }
```

Of course in a crude way , I can log all elements in a flat file, prefixing with some piece of information such as which sequence & where, and search them in whole file to reconstruct them back. However I am looking for a better robust & more structured alternative if available to deal with such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is sequential logging (with identifier) plus later reconstruction.

The issue of random access logging is two-fold:

- random writes are much slower than sequential writes on most disks
- how much space should you reserve ? what do you do when it's exhausted ?

Most of the times, logging is *not* the primary goal of your application; it's tacked on for investigation purposes. Because it's not essential, it should be unintrisive:

- does not work ? well, no reason the application should go down
- slow as hell ? well, no reason the application should be slowed down
- ...

Let an offline process do the heavy work and reconciliate the data.

Comment: So do you suggest writing the data tagging with the container & position like the first alternative in my question and post processing it to get back some nice JSON/XML format? Is there any standard protocol which supports such partial serialization (like something from boost serialization) ?  My intention has some similarity with things like serializing c++ namespace which can be reopened and more members can be written.

Comment: @abir: 1) yes, exactly. 2) No, if your data is simple enough then plain text (properly structured) will be sufficient; otherwise you'll need to turn to serialization. I would advise Protocol Buffers for the support in multiple languages (making writing tools easier) and just concatenating the messages one after the other in the log file (you can prefix them by their length upon writing).

Comment: Thanks. That sounds reasonable. I am even thinking to use sqlite database as a log file so that I can append/insert more items to the sequence & log them as a table row ! As log is guarded by a single boolean check I hope it will not incur any performance penalty when it is turned off, however I need to get some metric when it is turned on.